# configure confluence to call postfix setup to send email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, confluence, postfix-mta

We have confluence running on AWS instances and confluence is using AWS SES service SMPT server to send emails.
But now we want to send email through by using Postfix server ( Postfix setup already done on confluence AWS instance configuration of Postfix is also using AWS SES service SMPT server).

The Question is how to configure confluence to call postfix setup to send email? Whether we have to make any changes on the confluence configuration to call postfix mail server if yes how to do that? or we have to make changes on the postfix mail server to take request from confluence?

Note: Postfix basic setup is already been done by us.

Comment: It would be in confluence SMTP settings.  If your postfix instance is already moving email normally then just adjust confluence to connect to the server.

Comment: How to connect the postfix locally?  because postfix doesn't require authentication.

Comment: It's all in your smtp configuration of confluence.  Tell it to connect to localhost without authentication, and make sure postfix is setup accordingly.